# Metal shading language IR format

Tags: ios, metal

I'm trying Apple' Metal these days.
seems Metal shading language is very similar to `vulkan glsl`.

some questions:
1. is there any open source compiler to compile Metal shading language? or can it translate to another shading language? `glsl` or `spirv`?

2. what is the output format of the Apple' Metal compiler? I see someone mentions it is LLVM IR, but I cannot find any docs.
3. Metal games must send the compiled IR to the driver for rendering, right? can they use high-level Metal shading language, like `opengl` games use `glsl` directly?

wondering if there is some docs describe Metal IR from Apple?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `metal` tool to compile MSL is a modified version of `clang`, but I don't think the modifications have been open-sourced. It accepts many of the same command-line options as `clang` to produce various output files.

By default, it produces `.air` files, which are LLVM bitcode. You can use tools like `llvm-dis` to disassemble them.

Metal apps can use precompiled shaders or they can compile from MSL source at run-time. An app would use one of the `-newLibraryWithSource:...` methods of `MTLDevice` for the latter.

Comment: Since the `metal` compiler produces LLVM bitcode, it might be possible to convert it to SPIRV using the [SPIRV-LLVM-Translator](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-LLVM-Translator).

Answer (score 2):

From: https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf

> Metal uses clang and LLVM so developers get a compiler that delivers close to the metal performance for code executing on the GPU

More information on building here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Dev-Technique/Dev-Technique.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH8-SW1

> Building a Library File with Command Line Utilities

```
xcrun -sdk macosx metal MyLibrary.metal -o MyLibrary.air
xcrun -sdk macosx metallib MyLibrary.air -o MyLibrary.metallib
```